# How to make a callback function that draws a graph with a python dash button works

Tags: python, html, web

I want to draw a graph when I press the python dash button.
So I created a button called btn-run and a callback function called btn_run_click.
However, a new plot is not drawn when the button is pressed. The code is attached below.
Is there someone who can help?

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
    
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Br(),
    html.Button('start', id='btn-run', n_clicks=0,
                style={'width':'150px','height':'30px'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='main-plot', figure={}),
    html.Br()    
])

@app.callback(
    Output('main-plot', 'children'),
    Input('btn-run','n_clicks')
)
def btn_run_click(btn_run):
    
    if btn_run == 0 : return
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Fruits":['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas'],
        "Amount":[4,3,6]
    })
    
    fig = px.bar(df, x = "Fruits", y = "Amount", barmode='group')
    return dcc.Graph(figure=fig)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=8052)
```

Comment: it looks like btn-run > n_clicks is always 0 ... so it always just returns

Comment: When I remove, if btn_run==0 : return, plot does not appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made some minor changes to your code

```py
import dash
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Br(),
    html.Button('start', id='btn-run', n_clicks=0,
                style={'width': '150px', 'height': '30px'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='main-plot', figure={}),
    html.Br()
])


@app.callback(
    # change output to main-plot.figure
    Output('main-plot', 'figure'),
    Input('btn-run', 'n_clicks')
)
def btn_run_click(btn_run):
    #if btn_run == 0: return
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Fruits": ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas'],
        "Amount": [4, 3+btn_run, 6] 
    })

    fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruits", y="Amount", barmode='group')
    # just return the figure
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=8052)
```